# Select multiple types in LINQ Select

Tags: c#, linq

Can this be turned into a select statement?

```
foreach (var gf in CreateGenericFieldsOnInspection(model))
{
    simpleInspection.GenericFields.Add(gf.GenericFieldDefinition.Name,
                                       new LC360Carrier.Domain.Models.Import.GenericField
                                       {
                                           GenericFieldType = GenericFieldValueType.Text,
                                           Value = gf.Value
                                       });
}
```

Comment: short answer, **no**, because `simpleInspection.GenericFields.Add` returns nothing so any `.Select` that calls it just improper. anyway, you could always `.Select(x => new LC360Carrier.Domain.Models.Import.GenericField(){GenericFieldType = GenericFieldValueType.Text,Value = gf.Value})` -- this one called projection.

Comment: You can construct a new `Dictionary`, but you cannot add items to an existing one. The problem is that `Dictionary` lacks `AddRange` method.

Comment: You could create an `Add<TSrc, TKey,TValue>(this IDictionary<TSrc,TKey> dict, IEnumerable<TSrc> src, Func<TSrc, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSrc, TValue> valueSelector)` extension method but I'm not sure it is worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `GenericFields` is a `Dictionary<string, GenericFieldOrSomething>`. You could contort this into something really weird for the sake of using LINQ. But the purpose of LINQ is to query one or more `IEnumerable`s to either get a result or transform them into something else.

It's just like SQL. You query it to either get a set of records or some value like the sum of some numbers.

In your case you've already got a result set - whatever `CreateGenericFieldsOnInspection(model)` returns. It makes sense to do what you're already doing - `foreach` through the results and perform some action on each one of them.

LINQ would be handy if you needed to query that set. For example,

```
var filteredProperties = CreateGenericFieldsOnInspection(model)
    .Where(property => property.Name.StartsWith("X"));
```

But even then, once you had that collection, it would still make sense to use a `foreach` loop.

You'll see this sometimes - I did it when I first learned LINQ:

```
CreateGenericFieldsOnInspection(model).ToList()
    .ForEach(property => DoSomethingWith(property));
```

We convert something to a `List` because then we can use `.ForEach`. But there's no benefit to it. It's just `foreach` with different syntax and an extra step.

Comment: You can also create a `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable`.

Comment: True. I've seen it done. And I've used them. I've typed `.fo` after an `IEnumerable` and had three `ForEach` extensions come up from three different referenced libraries. But looking back I don't see a reason for it. Behind the scenes is just `foreach`. It just looks like a way to put more in a single line of code. I had to rehab myself to just use normal `foreach` because it's perfectly readable and good enough.

Comment: I (most of the time) completely agree, though in LINQPad My Extensions includes `ForEach`, `ForEach(Action)` and `Do(Action)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have an extension method that permits add.  I was just having trouble w the syntax.  Bagus Tesa, above was also helpful.  Thanks.

```
 simpleInspection.GenericFields = simpleInspection.GenericFields.Union(CreateGenericFieldsOnInspection(model).Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(x.GenericFieldDefinition.Name, new LC360Carrier.Domain.Models.Import.GenericField
            {
                GenericFieldType = GenericFieldValueType.Text,
                Value = x.Value
            }))).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```